# rails schema.db doesn't have id column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The schema.db file is supposed to be the authoritative source of the database schema. If that's the case, how come for a particular table mapped to a model, it doesn't show any columns designating id.

For example if I have a Subject model with a column called :title, how come all I see in the schema.db file is this:

```
create_table "subjects", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end
```

Is the id column somehow implied by rails after parsing the schema file? Opening up any instance of Subject in the rails console will clearly show that all Subject objects have an affiliated id.

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `create_table` function takes a couple of options that control this behavior.  Specifically, the `:id` and `:primary_key` options work like so:

> :id
>
> Whether to automatically add a primary key column. Defaults to true. Join tables for has_and_belongs_to_many should set it to false.
>
> :primary_key
>
> The name of the primary key, if one is to be added automatically. Defaults to id. If :id is false this option is ignored.
>
> Also note that this just sets the primary key in the table. You additionally need to configure the primary key in the model via self.primary_key=. Models do NOT auto-detect the primary key from their table definition.

(from the [rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-create_table))

Because of the default values of `id: true, primary_key: 'id'`, the ID column is left out of calls to `create_table`.